# Join & insert from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, json

I would like to know how to join to get final results in a table like this:

**Table 1 - Results Table**

| meta_id | order_item_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 88 | tracking_code | ER12144354656 |
| 2 | 88 | tracking_url | https://test1234.com.my |

From these tables

**Table 2 - to get meta_value**

| id | order_id | tracking_code | tracking_url |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | ER12144354656 | https://test1234.com.my |

**Table 3 - to get order_item_id value in Table 1**

| order_item_id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 88 | 123 |

Lastly to put tracking_code and tracking_url text matching by meta_value in table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally people want to go in the other direction, but anyway...

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE tracking
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,order_id INT NOT NULL
,tracking_code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,tracking_url VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tracking VALUES
(1,123,'ER12144354656','https://test1234.com');

CREATE TABLE order_detail
(order_id INT NOT NULL
,order_item_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(order_id,order_item_id)
);

INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES
(123,88);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY order_id,order_item_id,meta_key) id
     , d.*
     , meta_key
     , meta_value
  FROM order_detail d
  JOIN
     ( SELECT order_id
            , 'tracking_code' meta_key
            , tracking_code meta_value
         FROM tracking
        UNION ALL
       SELECT order_id
            , 'tracking_url' 
            , tracking_url 
         FROM tracking
     ) x
    ON x.order_id = d.order_id;
```

| id | order_id | order_item_id | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 88 | tracking_code | ER12144354656 |
| 2 | 123 | 88 | tracking_url | https://test1234.com |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fSfBXkfVZnzevHyb9BnMec/0)

Answer (score -1):

you should do this:

1. Create 2 temp tables same columns and same order.
2. insert into temp tables separate tracking _code and tracking_url
   3.Union 2 temp tables.
3. After get results you can delete temp tables.